# Change class of div based on a field's validation result

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to wrap fields in a `<div class="validation-error">` when they have validation errors, and in plain `<div>`s otherwise:

Validation Error:

```
<div class="validation-error">
    <sf:input  path="title" cssErrorClass="validation-error"/>
    <sf:errors path="title" cssErrorClass="validation-error" />
</div>
```

No Validation Error:

```
<div>
    <sf:input  path="title" cssErrorClass="validation-error"/>
    <sf:errors path="title" cssErrorClass="validation-error" />
</div>
```

How can I check that `title` has an error or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't apply `validation-error` class to whole `<div>` element of your input. I don't think that `<errors>` tag was meant to work like that.

What you could do is very simple and neat solution. Simply display error message with all proper classes and styles applied to it or don't display it at all. For instance:

```
<tr>
      <td><label>Username</label></td>
      <td><form:input id="username" path="nickname" /></td>
      <td><span id="usernameError" class="error"><form:errors path="nickname" /></span></td>
</tr>
```

When there is no error message, appropriate cell will be left blank and user won't see anything. However, if the message will be displayed - it will have proper styling thanks to `class="error"` notation in mine example.

Ohh, and you can use `divs, spans or any other elements if you wish`. I just tend to use `table` for forms.